# Is it possible/practical to use a Linux server to authenticate Windows devices?

Tags: linux, windows, authentication

I am from a small primary school and we are currently looking into getting a server purely for authentication. I do not want to push software to the devices or anything like that. I simply want to force the devices to input a username/password before they can use it (to keep track of who is using what for security purposes. We are getting more and more windows tablets in and it is hard for the teachers to keep track of who is using what).

I do not want to spend money so i thought using open source server software would be a better idea. I understand i will need a relatively good piece of hardware to then run this but that shouldn't be a problem to sort out.

I looked around at Apache, ClearOS and Ubuntu Server and they all look great but i can't seem to find any information regarding compatibility of Linux servers with windows.

So: Is it possible/practical to use a Linux server to authenticate Windows devices?
and if so, any recommendations?

Comment: While I realise this isn't an answer to your question, I would ask that you seriously consider why you don't just setup a proper Active Directory domain on a Windows server. It sounds like you're using a Windows ecosystem already, so it would be the best fit.

Comment: You say you want to authenticate windows devices. But I can not read this from your question. You seem to want to authenticate somewhere (Where? Against what service?) on a windows tablet. So the windows table just seems to be a device to login to some... ...WebPortal? Or do you want the user to authenticate before he can use the Windows Device?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's perfectly possible! You can set up a Linux Server as an LDAP server, which allows for users to use the same username and password to authenticate on all boxes (including Linux ones).

Some useful links:

- [Wikipedia page on LDAP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lightweight_Directory_Access_Protocol)
- [Ubuntu page on configuring OpenLDAP](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/openldap-server.html)

Comment: Excellent, just been reading through those links you sent me. Only thing i couldn't grasp was what i would need to do to the windows devices to tell them to connect to the server.

Comment: I have to admit I've not done it myself: does [this link](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ActiveDirectoryHowto) help? You'll need to set up Samba and have it talk to LDAP for authentication.

Comment: Okay, i more or less get the process now. I'm sure i'll run in to a multitude of problems seeming i'm new to this. Thanks for all your help.

Comment: using ldap is not sufficient. You need to use samba.

Answer (score 6):

I just wanted to add this as further support. It is possible(and fundamentally AWESOME) to use samba as a replacement for a windows server domain controller. Glancing at those links it looked(and i could have missed something) that it was focusing on ldap for authenticating linux users, rather than windows users.

Some information can be found(http://xmodulo.com/samba-primary-domain-controller.html)

but basically you will want to install samba Active Directory, and modify the config file

> sudo cp /etc/samba/smb.conf
>
> [global]
>
> workgroup = sambadomain    netbios name = sambapdc     server
>
> string = Samba PDC
>   
>  domain master = yes
>   
>    preferred master = yes
>   
>    domain logons = yes
>   
>    add machine script = /usr/sbin/useradd -N -g
>   
>    machines -c Machine -d /var/lib/samba -s /bin/false %u
>   
>       security =user
>   
>        encrypt passwords = yes
>   
>        wins support = yes
>   
>    name resolve order = wins lmhosts hosts bcast 
>     logon path = \%N\%U\profile 
>   
>    logon drive = H:
>   
>    logon home = \%N\%U

At the end of it you can then manage users with the command line.

> #to create user
>   
> sudo smbpasswd -a dan
>   
> #to activate user 
>   
>  sudo smbpassword -e dan 
>   
> #to give user login rights
>   
>  sudo net rpc rights grant "SAMBADOMAIN\dan" SeMachineAccountPrivilege SePrintOperatorPrivilege SeAddUsersPrivilege SeDiskOperatorPrivilege SeRemoteShutdownPrivilege 
>   
> #to add to domain groups.
>   
> sudo net groupmap add ntgroup="Administrator" unixgroup=root rid=512 type=d

Using this method your windows machines would join the domain as if it were a windows domain server providing authentication.

There are some more steps involved, but there is a wealth of information out there regarding using samba for AD :)

Comment: This is the route to go down rather than a "generic LDAP server" route unless you've got particular requirements that mean you're married to a specific LDAP server already.